# Convert 4 bytes to 32 bit float with high precision in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, byte, precision

I have 4 bytes like with the value as unsigned char are: 63 129 71 174.

Supposedly, when convert it to float, it should become [1.0099999904632568](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=049046048048057057057057057057048052054051050053054056).

However, all I got in return is 1.01, which is not enough precision for what I am doing.

I have used popular methods like memcpy or uninion but no avail, which led me to believe... is this some kind of limitation in C?

If so, what is the optimal solution? Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry for the bad example. I should have taken a better one for my case. Consider this 4 bytes: 0 1 229 13.

It is very small, like really really small. However, it's 4 bytes, so it still does represent a [float number](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?hexadecimal=0001E50D). However, C will just return 0. I put 16 number after decimal, and it just does not work.

So why, and how to work with such number?

EDIT 2: Sorry. My friend messed up. She gave me the 4 bytes sequence and said its 32 bit float, but turn out it's 32 but unsigned int. It pretty much messed up my entire afternoon. REALLY SORRY FOR BOTHERING.

I guess the conclusion here is: do not always trust your friend.

Comment: Most probably you are just printing the output with not enough precision.

Comment: Try `printf("%.10f", myFloat)` and check the result.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. It solved half of my problem. However, the other half, like for a number represented by, say 4 bytes: 0 1 229 13... It's a float, just really really small one. How can I work with it? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to print a really small/big `float`, you might want to print it in scientific notation, like this: `printf("%.10e\n", myFloat);`

Comment: For the second example, using `printf("%.50f", myFloat);` produces `0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000017400343421`

Comment: The bytes you give, hex 0x0001e50d, turn into a float with the exact value `1.7400343421060551014781227354585875576946396610863259292639044001544702811035136846840032376348972320556640625e-40`, i.e. `1.74003432 * 10^-40` so you need at least 40 digits after the decimal point or scientific notation.

Comment: Also note that if you convert 1.01 to an IEEE-754 single precision value, you will get that value, i.e. 1.0099etc. is the closest value.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786533/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-float-in-php) is how to convert byte array into float in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Using `memcpy()` really is the way to go.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  const unsigned char raw1[] = { 174, 71, 129, 63 };
  const unsigned char raw2[] = { 0, 1, 229, 13 };
  float x, y;
  memcpy(&x, raw1, sizeof x);
  memcpy(&y, raw2, sizeof y);
  printf("%.6f\n", x);
  printf("%g\n", y);
  return 0;
}
```

This prints `1.010000`, I don't think it's reasonable to expect more precision out of a `float`. Note that I swapped the order of the bytes, tested on little-endian system I think (ideone.com).

With `%g` for the second number, it prints `1.41135e-30`.

Comment: @WeatherVane It successfully recovered the float, which the OP was not able to do.